# How do I get all input args combined without redundancy?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I want to get all combinations without replacement for args (files) A, B and C.

That is I want to get the combinations

```
A B
B C
A C
```

without redundant ones like `B A`.

Is it possible to do that easily with GNU parallel?

My current command looks like:

```
 parallel 'echo {1} {2}' ::: (ls *txt) ::: (ls *txt)
```

but this prints all combos.

Ps. there are many more files than three, so general solutions only please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no elegant solution:

```
parallel 'test "{1}" \< "{2}" && echo {1} {2}' ::: *txt ::: *txt
```

From version 20170922 you can do:

```
$ parallel --plus echo {choose_k} ::: a b c ::: a b c
a b
a c
b c
```

Comment: Great! Never heard about test before; seems useful. I find that solution rather elegant btw.

Comment: In case you know the answer and it is very similar to the above: is there a way to include A A, B B and C C without adding B A and so on?

Comment: parallel --xapply echo ::: a b c ::: a b c; or simply parallel echo {} {} ::: a b c